# JSON colunm vs Reference key approach - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, foreign-key, jsonb

Which is a good database schema design by considering the performance and long-term large records?

Database: Postgres

I have two ways to design the table structure:

1. Use a JSON column
2. Go with a foreign key reference table?

Option 1: JSON column example,

Table 1:  Case (Keep all the Cases)

[image]

Table 2:  Tags (All the tags will be stored in this table)

[image]

Option 2: Have a Reference table

Table 3:  Tag_Case_Mapping

Should keep different records for each tags under the same case id.

[image]

I need to display tags that are associated with each case in UI, so have to write LINQ join query to display each cases and its respective tags. I can make it in both the way, but I curious about the way which is database design approach in terms of considering the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before deciding how to *store* any data, consider how you intend to *access* it, afterwards.

If you only ***ever*** want to look up a Case and then display all the Tags for that case, then "packing" all the Tags into a JSON column will be fine.
However, as soon as you *think* you *might*, possibly, want to find all the Cases with a particular Tag, or *group* of Tags, then properly Normalising your data, with a separate table linking Cases to Tags, is the way to go.

```
select * 
from cases ; 

+---------+-----------+
| case_id | case_text | 
+---------+-----------+
|      11 | ...       |
+---------+-----------+

select * 
from case_tags ; 

+---------+--------+
| case_id | tag_id | 
+---------+--------+
|      11 |      1 |
|      11 |      3 |
|      11 |      6 |
|      11 |     10 |
+---------+--------+

select c.* 
from case_tags ct 
inner join cases c on ct.case_id = c.case_id
where ct.tag_id ...
```

Put a composite Primary Key on both ( case_id and tag_id ) and then index them the other way around, to efficiently support queries going in "either direction".

Comment: Thanks, @Phill W. Obviously I will do more tags-based lookups. Hence as you suggest I will plan to normalize the data with a separate table.